# Declaring constants in Kotlin - calling functions at compile time

Tags: kotlin

For compile-time constants, is there a way of doing

```
const val myAngle = Math.toRadians(45.0)
```

without including the `Math.toRadians` function logic directly in code

```
const val myAngle = 45.0 / 180.0 * Math.PI
```

and without doing the calculation beforehand

```
const val myAngle = Math.PI / 2 // 45.0 degrees
```

i.e. is there a way of calling `Math.toRadians` at compile-time?

**Edit** - My usecase: I am trying to create some angle constants, I would like to input them in degrees, but I would like the stored constant to be in radians.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your use-case, as to what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MadhuBhat Question edited.

Comment: But isn't that completely against the concept of a compile-time constant? Hence I very much doubt that it's possible to achieve that.

Comment: If you have inputs, then you wouldn't have anything constant, right? Unless those are fixed also ;)

Comment: When I say input, I mean input them into my code, i.e. add the constant to my code. Hope that makes more sense.

Comment: @MadhuBhat No, it isn't; you can do it in C++, Rust, some other languages. Just not on JVM.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov yes exactly, I was talking about the context of the question, ie JVM :)

Comment: @MadhuBhat Ok, but "completely against the concept" seemed to imply a stronger claim to me.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov why would I talk about concepts outside the context of the question? For example, there are concepts which work differently in Kotlin and Java itself, even though both work on JVM. I don't understand why you're going at that bit of the comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The reason for that is that there's no guarantee that the return value of any function is a constant (can be computed in compile time).

It's perfectly fine to use `val myAngle = Math.toRadians(45.0)`, though.